# How to create an ActiveRecord object with a many-to-many relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, many-to-many

I have created a blank rails app (`rails new cheese_shop`), with two models and a join table. I am trying to create a cheese shop and specifying which cheeses it contains, at creation time, like this:

```rb
cheeses = [
  Cheese.create!(name: "Bree"),
  Cheese.create!(name: "Kačkavalj"),
]
Shop.create! name: "The Whistling Cheese", cheeses: cheeses
```

However, I'm getting this error:

```
SQLite3::ConstraintException: NOT NULL constraint failed: stocks.shop_id: INSERT INTO "stocks" ("cheese_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?)
```

Apparently, the shop ID is not inserted to the `stocks` table when I create the shop. Is it possible to fix this, without having to do it in two steps (i.e. without first creating the Shop, and then adding the cheeses?)

#### Here are my models:

```rb
class Cheese < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :shops, through: :stocks
  has_many :stocks
end

class Shop < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :cheeses, through: :stocks
  has_many :stocks
end

class Stock < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :shop
  belongs_to :cheese
end
```

#### My migrations look like this:

```rb
class CreateTables < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :cheeses do |t|
      t.string :name, null: false

      t.timestamps null: false
    end

    create_table :shops do |t|
      t.string :name, null: false

      t.timestamps null: false
    end

    create_table :stocks do |t|
      t.integer :shop_id,   null: false
      t.integer :cheese_id, null: false

      t.integer :amount
      t.float :price
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

maybe you should try to use nested attributes:

```
class Shop < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :cheeses, through: :stocks
    has_many :stocks

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :stocks
end
```

and then you will be able to do something like:

```
cheese = Cheese.create!(name: "Bree")
params = { attrib: { name: "The Whistling Cheese", stocks_attributes: { cheese_id: cheese.id} } }
Shop.create params[:attrib]
```

here is doc: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html

Answer (score 0):

It turns out Rails creates the associations in two steps, first leaving out the Shop ID, then setting the Shop IDs with an `UPDATE`, all in one transaction. So The `NOT NULL` constraints are causing the problem.

Changing this:

```
  t.integer :shop_id,   null: false
  t.integer :cheese_id, null: false
```

…to this:

```
  t.integer :shop_id
  t.integer :cheese_id, null: false
```

…solves the problem, although I'm unhappy with this since now I cannot rely on the database to ensure the integrity of my data.